# Changing number values for text on Y Axis label for dc.js ScatterPlot

Tags: d3.js, charts, scatter-plot, dc.js, axis-labels

I have a scatter plot that charts unique events per date on my X axis and when they happened on each day, by the second, on the Y axis.

To accomplish this I took the date data that I use for the X axis, and ran it through a function that would output the exact second of the day in which the event happened (0 to 86400). In that sense, my Y axis goes from 0 seconds to 86400 seconds.

This allowed me to represent each even uniquely as a dot on my chart down to the second.

I'm pretty happy with the outcome of my chart:

[image: Scatter plot image]

The only issue is my Y label goes from 0 to 86400. I would like to change the text to a familiar HH AM/PM format, perhaps something along the lines of "0 to 23, where ie: if (y value = 3600) return "1 AM".

My scatterplot looks like this:

```
scatterPlot
        .width(window.innerWidth-100)
        .height(window.innerHeight/2)
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
        .brushOn(false)
        .mouseZoomable(true)
        // .title(function (d) {
        //     return "Event: " + d['text'];
        // })
        .clipPadding(5)
        .yAxisLabel("Hour of the day")
        .elasticY(true)
        .dimension(eventsByDateAndHourDim)
        .group(eventsByDateAndHourGroup);
```

I tried to do this:

```
scatterPlot.yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) {
    if (domain = 43200)
        return "12 PM";
})
```

But that only changes all labels to "12 PM". I'm not sure how to refer to the actual value of my Y domain.

I tried using the group "if (eventsByDateAndHourGroup = 43200)..." but that didn't work either.

Comment: You're on the right track. There's a syntax error in your `tickFormat` function, I assume it's missing "`domain) {`"? This function will be passed the Y value, so maybe I'm not clear on your question.

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted wrong!

The function is:

scatterPlot.yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) {
    if (domain = 43200)
        return "12 PM";
     })

Very hard to get formatting done right on the comments though!

I've edited the main post text to reflect the fix. Still, all labels are 12 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to the function passed to the [`tickFormat()` method](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickFormat) is the Y coordinate which needs to be formatted.

So you should be able to do something like

```
scatterPlot.yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) {
    var hour = Math.floor(d/3600),
        pm = hour > 11;
    if(pm) hour -= 12; 
    if(hour === 0) hour = 12; 
    return String(hour) + (pm ? ' PM' : ' AM');
});
```

Or you can use `d3.time.format.utc` for a more robust, elegant solution:

```
var hourFormat = d3.time.format.utc('%I %p');
scatterPlot.yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) {
    var date = new Date(d*1000);
    return hourFormat(date);
});
```

This is somewhat less efficient, because `Date` objects are slow, but it probably doesn't matter for processing a dozen ticks.